# Which creatures can follow you through or otherwise open doors?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I would love to know which creatures can follow you through a door.  I could test this myself, but as I only have access to a console version doing so would be arduous, to say the least.

**Bonus question**: If a creature can open 'swinging'( i.e. a door that will physically move and not just load another game zone ) door can they also open a 'loading' door, and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that any creature that can be expected to use a door in real life can and will open a door in Oblivion as well, plus any creature that can cast spells or use weapons.

It also seems that door-opening creatures will not open just about any door - maybe there are per-creature or per-environment limits to their roaming capabilities. For example, some bandits won't leave their cave even though they pass through (loading) doors within the cave, while others may follow you throughout all of Tamriel.

Comment: Excellent start here.  I'm looking for more specific info, like a list of creatures/monsters that will do follow.  Even still, if there aren't any new or better answers here soon( there probably won't be ) I'll go ahead and accept this as the answer.  I'll likely get around to testing this myself and making a list eventually.  When I do so I'll add the info to this answer if there isn't one better.  P.S.:  Thanks for mentioning the bit about the creatures being 'selective' as to which doors they 'choose' to open.  I didn't think about that.